# Is there a database for immunoglobulin domain structure?

Tags: immunology, database, sequence-analysis

is there a database where I can find the sequences of the hypervariable domain of immunoglobulins and the sequences of the related antigens? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of databases that exist, though the one you would want to use will likely depend on what you need it for. The one that's recommended at my university is [IgBlast](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/igblast/), associated with The National Center for Biotechnology Information (NCBI), however I've seen [IMGT](http://www.imgt.org) as a recommended source, as well; it seems to have a wider array of tools. That being said, I can't say which you might find more beneficial, as I'm uncertain as to how you'd be using the resource.

Comment: essentially I am interested in the primary sequence of the variable regions of the immunoglobulins (let's say GALMF) and the corresponding antigenic primary sequence (let's say CHYR), this sort of association. Thank you, I will have a look at those databases.

Comment: actually, these databases are blasting tools to search for patterns. I am looking for a list of sequences hits with both TCR of Ig and related antigens, if any.